# How do i get the value from a id, php

Tags: php, woocommerce, new-operator

[Fondend where it should connect with the New Width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnSR.png)

[Admin data tabs to control and set a begin size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6icR.png)

If i change the placeholder to the value and set it to 8 or something it doesnt work, and if it works i need it to get the value from a id

```
woocommerce_form_field('custom_field1', array(
          'id' => 'Hwidth',
          'label' => __( 'Width', 'woocommerce' ),
          'placeholder' => 'id=Hwidth',
          'css'  => 'width: 20px;',
          'type' => 'number',
          'required'    => true, // Or false
          'custom_attributes' => array(
                                    'step' => '0.1',
                                    'min' => '3' 
                                    )
        )
);
```

Comment: Thanks :), But how do i get the value from a id. I have a other field and it has to get the saved number value from that.

Comment: Where do you add this field? On the product page? In the admin panel?

Comment: **placeholder** is to display an alternative text to the user and not a **value**. The value can be accessed by **ID** after submitting the form

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdanim Im trying to make a aspect ratio pricing combiend with woocommerce its all in PHP. i have tabs in admin panel and i want when u enter a value there that it shows on the product page.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of where they should be displayed? Do these fields affect the price?

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani i added screenshots, and it doesnt affect the price yet. but it will be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign a value to the `woocommerce_form_field` function. Here is the code you need:

```
$width  = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_width', true );

woocommerce_form_field( '_custom_width', // Field ID
    array(
        'name'              => '_custom_width',
        'placeholder'       => 'Please enter width',
        'css'               => 'width: 20px;',
        'type'              => 'number',
        'required'          => true, // Or false
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => '0.1',
            'min' => '3' 
        ),
    ),
    $width // Saved Value 
);
```